# How to check printer can support the many copies?

Tags: c++, wpf, printing, mfc

I am working in a project MFC and WPF (called A). It has a print preview view, and there is a button "Print", a combobox for selecting the printer, a spin control for copies. All them are manually created.

I have created a project follow the instruction (called B):
http://www.functionx.com/visualc/printing/docviewprinting.htm

When I run this project (B), a tool bar with Print button is automatically created. If I print many copies on the printer which don't support many copies, a message box apprears:

> This printer cannot support this many copies.
>
> Number of copies will be set to printer maximum of 1.

So it can check printer supports the many copies.

And in the project A, I cannot check whether printer support the many copies or not. I have done follow the instruction:

http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?97158-How-to-print-multiple-copies

By using `if(lpdm->dmFields & DM_COPIES)`. But it doesn't effect.

**So can you show me how to check printer support the many copies?**

I have searched on the websites:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/167345

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/140285

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28603484/How-to-detect-or-better-prevent-print-drivers-making-multiple-copies-in-MS-MFC-C.html

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa251430(v=vs.60).aspx

but there isn't any result.

**The problem is resolved.**

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `DeviceCapabilities` with `DC_COPIES` to test if printer supports multiple copies

[DeviceCapabilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183552(v=vs.85).aspx)

> DC_COPIES
>  Returns the number of copies the device can print.

Example:

```
CPrintDialog prn(FALSE); 
prn.GetDefaults(); 

CString device = prn.GetDeviceName();
//hDevNames was locked by CPrintDialog::GetDeviceName()
GlobalUnlock(prn.m_pd.hDevNames);

CString port = prn.GetPortName();
//hDevNames was locked by CPrintDialog::GetPortName()
GlobalUnlock(prn.m_pd.hDevNames);

DWORD copies = DeviceCapabilities(device, port, DC_COPIES, NULL, NULL);
```

The return value is 1 if it doesn't support multiple copies.

Use `DEVMODE` and `DM_COPIES` to assign the number of copies.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Today I can test in the project (I cannot test in my home). So sorry for my delay.

Answer (score 0):

A little more information for someone.

From the printer is selected in combobox, I get `PrintCapabilities` then check `MaxCopyCount`.

```
    if (1 == currPrinter.GetPrintCapabilities().MaxCopyCount)
    {
     //The printer doesn't support many copies.
    }
```

Comment: `GetPrintCapabilities` is not C++ or MFC as far as I know. I think this is WPF solution. Maybe you should add WPF tag to your question or make that clear.

Comment: Thank for your advice, I added tag WPF.